# How to use LIMIT in HBase .Net REST Client

Tags: .net, apache, hbase, limit

I have a requirement to retrieve one row from HBase table from a given column family. LIMIT can be used in Java API and HBase shell console. I need a way to do it in HBase .Net REST API developed by microsoft.

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience on .Net client, but REST API (Stargate) let you add the 'limit' parameter.

this is an example to request only one row:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" https://localhost:8080/ExampleScanner/*?limit=1
```

source:
[Apache HBase REST](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html)